# What is the best way to distort the shape of this leaf image plane? (i'm a complete beginner)

Tags: modeling, texturing

[image]

I'm making a library of leaves. Once I have the image plane and all the maps assigned. What is the best method to distort the image plane to make the leaves look more natural/realistic shapes?

Comment: so all your meshes will be subdivided planes like the one we see on your picture? In that case just enable the Proportional Editing option, and move some vertices?

Answer (score 0):

have not used Blender much in a long time either but hope this is what you're looking for.

I screen captured your leaf image used it as a reference to model a grid around it deleting the excess, made a material to map the image to the leaf, did a quick UV map , set displacement to bump, went into shading and changed settings to distort the surface.

[image]

rendered single leaf and it looked good , in object mode duplicated it nine times , took each leaf into edit mode > sculpt mode and used the elastic deform tool to distort the shape from flat plane.

[image]

I rendered both sides this is the bottom so it seemed to work good.

Comment: Thanks for your help, yes I looked into editing the plane in sculpt mode. I think that's the easiest way. Thanks